# TCPClient not receiving data

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I want to use StreamReader and StreamWriter to receive and send data over TCPClient.NetworkStream. The code is depicted below:
Client code:

```
 using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
            {
                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9001);
                client.Connect(localEndPoint);
                client.NoDelay = true;

                using(NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
                {                    
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                    {
                        writer.AutoFlush = true;
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {    

                            string message = "Client says: Hello";
                            writer.WriteLine(message);

                // If I comment the line below, the server receives the  first message
                // otherwise it keeps waiting for data
                           string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                           Console.WriteLine(response);
                        }
                       ;
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Note: If I comment the reader.ReadToEnd(); then the server receives the message, otherwise the server keeps waiting for data from the client. Is ReadToEnd the problem?**



Server code accepts a connection asynchronously, but handles the data in a synchronous manner:

```
class Program
    {
        private static AsyncCallback tcpClientCallback;
        static void Main(string[] args){

            IPEndPoint localEndPoint =  new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),9001);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localEndPoint);

            listener.Start();

            tcpClientCallback = new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback);
            AcceptConnectionsAysnc(listener);

            Console.WriteLine("Started Aysnc TCP listener, press any key to exit (server is free to do other tasks)");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void AcceptConnectionsAysnc(TcpListener listener)
        {
            listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(tcpClientCallback, listener);
        }

        static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received a conenct request");
            TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)result.AsyncState;

            // We are starting a thread which waits to receive the data
            // This is not exactly scalable
            Task recieveTask = new Task(() => { HandleRecieve(result, listener); });
            recieveTask.Start();

            AcceptConnectionsAysnc(listener);
        }


        // This makes a blocking call - that means until the client is ready to
        // send some data the server waits
        private static void HandleRecieve(IAsyncResult result, TcpListener listener)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for data");

            using (TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result))
            {
                client.NoDelay = true;

                using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                        {
                            writer.AutoFlush = true;
                            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
                            watch.Start();
                            string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            watch.Stop();
                            Console.WriteLine("Time: " + watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                            Console.WriteLine(data);


// Send a response to client
                                writer.WriteLine("Response: " + data);
                            }

                        }
                    }            


                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: maybe there is something with read/write speed in stream..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A stream doesn't end until it is *closed*. Currently, both client and server are holding their connections *open*, and both is trying to read **to the end** from the other - and when they do, will close themselves. This is a deadlock: neither will ever get to the end, so neither will ever close (which would allow the other to get to the end).

Options:

- use raw sockets, and have the client close the *outbound* stream after sending:

  ```
  socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
  ```

  this lets the *server* read to completion, which lets the server close, which lets the client read to completion; the client can still read from the *inbound* stream after closing the outbound socket.
- use a different termination metaphor than `ReadToEnd`; for text-based protocols, end-of-line is the most common (so: `ReadLine`); for binary protocols, a length-prefix of the message is the most common. This allows each end to read *the next message*, without ever having to read to the end of the stream. In this scenario it would only *be* a single message, but the strategy still works.
- use a different protocol if you find the above tricky; http is good for single request/response operations, and can be handled at the server via `HttpListener`.

Additionally, I'd be very careful about using `ReadToEnd` on a server (or even `ReadLine`) - that could be a good way of locking up threads on the server. If the server needs to cope with high throughput and lots of connections, async-IO based on raw sockets would be preferred.

Comment: Yes ReadToEnd was the issue, replacing it with ReadLine helped.

Comment: @Ngm personally I would still have reservations about using `ReadLine` on a server - see my last paragraph. I have some TCP servers that do this type of thing, and even looking for and end-of-line I use async-IO and just scan for bytes 13/10.

Comment: Thanks Marc,so what is the best option in case I do not want to use Raw sockets and use streams?

Comment: @Ngm you're tying my hands a bit there... that is "what is the best option if we assume I don't want to use the best option" (and btw, you can use *sockets* without use the `Stream` class). The `Socket` class gives you the best async options, but `TcpClient` gives you *most* of that via `GetStream()` then `BeginRead()` on the stream. It really depends how critical the server is, and what the throughput is. `StreamReader` *will work*... as long as your clients are well-behaved.